# How to fix the table height?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I want to fix the table height to 600px, eve if the content goes long.

Answer (score 15):

Try wrapping the table within a `div` tag, and setting the CSS properties of the `div` like so:

```
div.tablewrapper {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This will make a scrollbar appear if the table's height exceeds 600 pixels. If you don't want to always force the height to 600px if the table it too small to take up that much space, but instead just want 600px to be the *max*, use `max-height` instead of `height`.

Comment: This totally worked for me. thank you very much. :)
At first I tried putting the style under #facebox .content but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @paologranadalim: what `facebox`?

Answer (score 0):

```
div.tablewrapper {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

this works for to fix a page exact 600px as height..

Answer (score -6):

See the sample code below..

```
<div style="height:100px; overflow:auto;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>sad<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
asd<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```