# Give a table a fixed height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my table a fixed height - I'll eventually use overflow to scroll. But my height is being ignored.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hop061md/)

CSS:

```
table {
    height: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            hello
            ......
```

Comment: try looking in Chrome Dev Tools to find out what styling is being applied to the element. it's worth reading up on specificity for CSS.

Comment: The styles are being applied to the table element, just not working.

Comment: use `display:inline-block` on table

Comment: As spirits comment said, the table needs a specific display such as (inline)block togeteher with an overflow(-y) setting. Also mentioned in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970362/setting-a-max-height-on-a-table.  Having said that, just want to mention looking into flexbox or other alternative layouts may be easier than adapting a table for layout purposes

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hop061md/

Use `display:inline-block` on table.

```css
table {
  max-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hello
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow` property works to the `block` elements only...And `table` default display property is `display:table`...

So I think setting `table` to `display:block` will be not a good idea...

So Just wrap your `table` into a `div` and then apply `height` and `overflow:auto`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```